# Probability PDF CDF Help

Tags: probability

I'm looking at a STEP question and I'm a little confused by the logic of the method, and i'm really hoping someone could clarify what is going on for me. I have a good knowledge (At least I thought), as some STEP II and III questions are accessible but this one , I just can't wrap my head around - there must be a gap in my understanding for sure.

It would be difficult for me to rewrite the question on here but here is the video of the question AND the solution, (it's not too long I assure you, just the first 2/3 minutes, it's the entry to the question that has got me scratching my head)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKjQ2RTfltU&frags=pl%2Cwn

> An internet tester send $n$ e-mails simultaneously at time $t=0$. Their arrival times at their destinations are independent random variables each having probability density function $ke^{-kt}$ where $t>0$ and $k>0$. The random variable $T$ is the time of arrival of the e-mail that arrives first at its destination. Show that the probability density function of $T$ is $nke^{-nkt}$

I understand the calculation later on in the question for the expectation and even the very last part of the question, I just find it difficult to understand how it is logical to consider what this guy has considered in the first 2/3 minutes of the video. Is there a nicer explanation why he considered $P(T>t)$ and not $P(T<t)$, could it even be done this way? Is this a general method for this 'type' of question?

I do see what he has done, and understand it, it's just something that I would never have even considered and makes me uncomfortable.

Thank you for your help, and I do apologise for the awkwardness of the question.

Comment: Many people (myself included) are not inclined to watch a video and try to figure out what your actual question is. Can you just write it here?

Comment: Hi, I'm really sorry, yes I'll write it now

Comment: An internet tester send n e-mails simultaneously at time t=0. Their arrival times at their destinations are independent random variables each having probability density function ke^(-kt) where t>0 and k>0. The random variable T is the time of arrival of the e-mail that arrives first at its destination. Show that the probability density function of T is nke^-(nkt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps:

- The probability a particular email arrives by time $t$ is $1-e^{-kt}$ and that it does not arrive by time $t$ is $e^{-kt}$ - use integration of the pdf if necessary
- So the probability none of $n$ independent emails arrive by time $t$ is $\mathbb P(T \gt t)= \left(e^{-kt}\right)^n = e^{-nkt}$ and thus the probability the first arrives before time $t$ is $\mathbb P(T \le t)=1-e^{-nkt}$ - now differentiate this CDF to get the pdf for the first arrival time

You use $\mathbb P(T \gt t)$ at the start of the second step because you can calculate it from the first step

If you had instead been calculating the pdf for the arrival times $S$ of the last email, you would not have used it, instead saying the probability all of $n$ independent emails arrive by time $t$ is $\mathbb P(S \le t)= \left(1-e^{-kt}\right)^n $ and then differentiating

Comment: Hi Henry, thank you so much for your response I really appreciate it. However, I'm still a little confused, by no fault of your own I assure you. My questions are, why can't you just use the PDF that the question gives you? What's the difference? What has constrained the PDF you have calculated to represent that of the first email? (Like what if the question asked for the second or third email). Isn't the 1-e^(-nkt) the probability of all emails arriving before t not just one email? Why isn't integrating immediately between 0 and t the cdf for the first email? Sorry for the question mountain!

Comment: @Dinglevak: in answer to your questions: just using the pdf and raising to the power of $n$ would not work with other distributions such as a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$; the logic is you want the CDF representing the probability at least one email has arrive by time $t$ and you can find this as the complement of none of the emails arriving by that time (if you disagree then what do you think that probability is?); integrating the pdf of $ke^{-kx}$ between $0$ and $t$ gives the $1-e^{-kt}$ that I stated

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I don't wish to take up much more of your time as i'm certainly feeling that it's a misunderstanding on my part. However, why would the probability of one arriving before time t and n-1 arriving after time t not represent the cdf of that 'first' email arriving before t (or 'first')? If you know of any reading I could do please let me know as I would like to inform myself better on this. - I'm certain there's an understanding that I'm overlooking. Nevertheless, I reiterate my gratitude for your time and patience, it means a lot to me.

Comment: @Dinglevak If two or more arrived before time $t$, then that would also be included in the event that the first arrival was before time $t$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $Y_1, Y_2, \cdots, Y_n$ be independent random variables and let $Z = \min\{Y_1,Y_2,\cdots,Y_n\}$. Then
$$\Pr\{Z > z\} = \Pr\{\min\{Y_1,Y_2,\cdots,Y_n\} > z\} = \Pr\{Y_1>z\}\Pr\{Y_2>z\}\cdots \Pr\{Y_n>z\}.$$
In this type of problems, it's a good idea to consider $\Pr\{Y_i > z\}$.